# why do i have a MSB3073 error if i don't even have any post build events

Tags: c++, msbuild

I had a MSB3073 error and i can't understand how the solutions online work because it says it is a post event build error or like the solutions are about it yet i literitly have nothing in the post build event box.

the error description:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Users\yanme\OneDrive\桌面\my creations\games i made\sdl2 mining game\packages\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.210806.1\build\native....\bin"cppwinrt @"x64\Release\sdl2 mining game.vcxproj.cppwinrt_plat.rsp"" exited with code 1.    sdl2 mining game    C:\Users\yanme\OneDrive\桌面\my creations\games i made\sdl2 mining game\packages\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.2.0.210806.1\build\native\Microsoft.Windows.CppWinRT.targets  656

Comment: Notice the command that is failing is `cppwinrt`. Did you realise that you are running that command? Do you know what it does? I've read a description and I have no idea what it is for.

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/cppwinrt) for cppwinrt. Assuming that, like me, this means nothing to you, then I suspect you have accidentally picked some build option that inappropriately invokes this program.

Comment: @john where are the build settings you suspect i accidentally picked some build option that invokes cppwinrt

Comment: @john i think cppwinrt makes it so windows api is usable on c++17

Comment: The Windows API is useable from C++17 without any special treatment.. As you might realise I don't really know what I'm talking about here, but maybe you have created a project like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/console-uwp).

Comment: In any case the best thing would be to delete this project and recreate it from scratch. Or do you get this problem with every project you create? A bit more background in what are doing (or trying to do) would help to solve the problem.

Comment: @john i made an empty c++ project but know that you mention that i might have made a UWP project,i remembered that i accidentally made a UWP thing in the project

Comment: Well that seems to explain it.